# Lotus Script Agent not working on Domino 9 server

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an export to Excel agent that works great on my old 8.5 server.  When I moved the database to a 9.0.1 server, the agent only exports one line at a time.  If there are 30 lines in the view, you have to run the agent 30 times.  What is different on a Domino 9 that would stop the agent from running through each line in the view?`Sub WriteViewasExcel (view As NotesView)

```
%REM
Agent ExporttoExcel
Created Mar 11, 2010 by Brian Moore/usr/nbt
Description: Comments for Agent
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize()
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim qs As NotesView
    Dim nv As NotesViewNavigator
    Dim ne As NotesViewEntry
    Dim Doc As NotesDocument    
    Set db = s.Currentdatabase
    Set qs = db.GetView("Export")
    Set nv = qs.CreateViewNav
    Set ne = nv.GetFirst
    Dim filename As String

    Print |Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel|
    filename="Excel "+db.Title+" "+Format(Now, "yyyy-mmm-d hhmm")+".xls" 'file name which will be suggested to user to save the resulting Excel file 
    Print |Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="|+filename+|"| 'Triggers the save/open browser prompt instead of embedding the spreadsheet in the browser
    Print ""

    Print |<table border="1"><tr>
        <td width="135"> <Center><b>Store Name</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>Date</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>Nontax clothing sales</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="blue">Tax textile sales</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="red">Furniture Sales</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="green">Elec/Mech Appl/Fixture Sales</td></font> </b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b> Shoe Sales</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="blue">Wares Sales</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="red">Total Discounts</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="green">Taxable Income</td></font> </b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>Tax Amount</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="blue">Credit Total</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="red">Payout Total</td></b></font> 
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="green">Actual Deposit</td></font> </b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>MC/VISA Sales</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="blue">AMEX Sales</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b><font color="red">Gift Certificates</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>Customer Count</td></b>
        <td width="80"> <Center><b>Total Donations</td></b></font></Center>
        </tr>|

    While Not(ne Is Nothing)

        Set doc = ne.Document 
        Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("exported" , "yes")
        Call doc.Save(True, False)

        Print|<tr> <td>| + ne.ColumnValues(0) + |</td> | 'Store Name
        Print|<td> | + ne.ColumnValues(1) + | </td> | 'Date
        Print|<td> | + ne.ColumnValues(2) + | </td> | 'Non Tax Clothing Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="blue">| + ne.ColumnValues(3) + | </font> </td> | 'Taxable Textile Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(4) + | </font> </td> | 'Furniture Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="green">| + ne.ColumnValues(5) + | </font> </td> | 'Elec/Mech Appliance/Fixture Sales
        Print|<td> | + ne.ColumnValues(6) + | </td> | 'Shoe Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="blue">| + ne.ColumnValues(7) + | </font> </td> | 'Wares Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(8) + | </font> </td> | 'Total Discounts
        Print|<td> <font color="green">| + ne.ColumnValues(9) + | </font> </td> | 'Taxable Income
        Print|<td> | + ne.ColumnValues(10) + | </td> | 'Tax Amount
        Print|<td> <font color="blue">| + ne.ColumnValues(11) + | </font> </td> | 'Credit Total
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(12) + | </font> </td> | 'Payout Total
        Print|<td> <font color="green">| + ne.ColumnValues(13) + | </font> </td> | 'Actural Deposits
        Print|<td> | + ne.ColumnValues(14) + | </td> | 'MC/VISA Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="blue">| + ne.ColumnValues(15) + | </font> </td> | 'AMEX Sales
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(16) + | </font> </td> | 'Gift Certificates
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(17) + | </font> </td> | 'Customer Count
        Print|<td> <font color="red">| + ne.ColumnValues(18) + | </font> </td> | 'Total Donations

        Set ne = nv.GetNext(ne)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Add after the code line

```
Set qs = db.GetView("Export")
```

the line

```
qs.AutoUpdate = False
```

Your view navigator gets confused when documents get discarded from view while navigator tries to get from entry to entry. `qs.AutoUpdate = False` prevents all entries in view during agent run.

Comment: Thanks Knut.  I'll give that a shot.  But why did it work on an older server?  Curious.

Comment: Probably it's an improvement of Domino 9 of being able to refresh view navigator and underlying view during agent run. It's not really something you need in your case...

Comment: First, you should indicate that this answered your question.... Second, if you used some form of error handling you would quickly learn that the view navigator was throwing an error on the line Set ne = nv.GetNext( ne )